# jQuery splits ajax response with '...'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've got an ajax call to a mvc controller which returns a partial view and it seems like jquery might be splitting up the response with '...'. The response consist of 938 rows of

```
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
```

Im using this static data for debugging purposes.

The ajax call looks like this:

```
function FetchList(arg1,arg2) {
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: '/Controller/Action',

    data: { Argument1: arg1, Argument2: arg2 },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "html",
    contentType: 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {

    },
    error: function () {

    }
});
```

When looking at the data in the success-function I can see that on row 469(half  of the response row size) three dots is presented '...'. When looking at the raw response in fiddler the three dots is not in the response.

If i limit the number of rows returned to 900; no dots is appearing in the response.

What's going on here? Are there some kind of magic size limit im not aware of or something?

jQuery version 1.12 is used.

Comment: How are you "looking at the data" exactly? Please post the code you're using to do that, or clarify the way you do it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Im looking at the data in the visual studio debugger and Chrome developer tools.

Comment: So most likely the Visual Studio debugger is adding those three dots. You can confirm that by having something like `$('#debugDiv').text(data);` with a `<div id="debugDiv"></div>` present in your page, and see what actual data you get back.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, you are right. It's the debugger who adds those dots. Im an idiot :( I cant set your comment as an answer, can i?

Comment: Well it was a guess, so now that it's confirmed, will post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not jQuery's fault, but rather the tool you're using to view the data.

Many debuggers will truncate long strings after certain amount of characters for ease of reading, Visual Studio Debugger is one of them.

If you want to be 100% sure you see what you really get, use plain old debugging:

```
 $('#debugDiv').text(data);
```

While you have this in your page:

```
<div id="debugDiv"></div>
```